# Impedance inverter transformation from series lumped resonators to lambda/2 resonators

Tags: rf, filter, impedance, transmission-line, microwave

Suppose I have the following series of filter transformations beginning with a lumped element bandpass filter and concluding with shunt susceptances-

[image]

The transformation from step (a) to step (b), and from step (c) to (d) makes intuitive sense to me based on the general theory of j and k immitance inverters.  But going from step (b) to step (c) does not make intuitive sense to me.  A half-wave line resonator typically forces the input impedance looking into it to be equal to what is connected on its output/load side.  But how does a series lumped resonator end up being equivalent to a half-wave line resonator in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/impedance-transformation/).

Basically, a half wave transmission line acts like a series tuned circuit and, when resonant, it will act as a direct connection between input and output (just like a series tuned circuit at resonance).